# error when inserting shell variable to beginning of a file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to append bash variable (which has html tags) at the beginning of a file.

```
INSERTTO=<h2>title</h2>
<li>sdfdsf</li>
```

Below is the command I am using -

```
sed -i '1i'$INSERTTO file.html
```

But i am getting error -

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 177: unknown command: `<'
```

Do i need to encode the html tags in INSERTTO variable ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use quotes:
`INSERTTO='<h2>title</h2>
<li>sdfdsf</li>'`

Then try this:

`sed "1 i $INSERTTO" file.html`

Answer (score 0):

Start with some text in your file, e.g.

```
$ cat file
some text
```

Then you need your variable to contain an explicit `'\n'` character where the line break is, e.g. `INSERTTO='<h2>title</h2>\n<li>sdfdsf</li>'`. Then you can use the `sed` expression to place both lines as the beginning lines in the file, e.g.

```
$ INSERTTO='<h2>title</h2>\n<li>sdfdsf</li>'; sed "1i $INSERTTO" file
<h2>title</h2>
<li>sdfdsf</li>
some text
```

Now at present, what will be done has only been written to the terminal `stdout`. To modify the file in place, you will need to add the `-i` option for `sed` (or `-i.bak` to save a backup of the original file with the `.bak` extension. (however you prefer to do it)

Answer (score 0):

I offer you an `ed(1)` solution.

```
INSERTTO=<h2>title</h2>
<li>sdfdsf</li>

printf '%s\n' 1i "$INSERTTO" . w | ed -s file.html
```

- Assuming the file is not empty that will work. otherwise use `0a` as the address and command instead of `1i`

... Or use the `cat(1)` and `mv(1)`

```
INSERTTO=<h2>title</h2>
    <li>sdfdsf</li>
```

Add the `stdin` flag and use a `herestring` works in bash but not in POSIX shells.

```
cat - file.html <<< "$INSERTTO"
```

You should see the output to stdout, redirect it to another file and move that file to the original file, something like this.

```
cat - file.html <<< "$INSERTTO"  > tempfile && mv tempfile file.html
```

However if the html file is a symlink then it is now broken... a work around would be to use another `cat`.

```
cat - file.html <<< "$INSERTTO"  > tempfile && cat tempfile > file.html && rm tempfile.
```

- `tempfile` is just an example you should take a loot at [How to create a tempfile in a secure manner](http://localhost/wiki/BashFAQ/062)